# DonationAlerts Centrifuge connection error { code: 3003, reason: 'bad request' }

Tags: node.js, websocket

Необходимо подключиться к каналу DonationAlerts, чтобы в live-режиме получать события донатов.

`node -v`: v18.18.0
`centrifuge`: ^5.0.0
`ws`: ^8.14.2

Опираюсь на документацию https://www.donationalerts.com/apidoc#introduction__centrifugo.

```
import { Centrifuge } from 'centrifuge'
import WebSocket from 'ws'

const DAws = 'wss://centrifugo.donationalerts.com/connection/websocket';
const centrifuge = new Centrifuge(DAws, {
    debug: true,
    websocket: WebSocket,
});
centrifuge.on(
    'disconnected',
    ctx =>  {
        console.log("disconnected ctx", ctx);
    }
);
```

Последним `console.log`-ом получаю:

```
disconnected ctx { code: 3003, reason: 'bad request' }
```

**Конкретно это и является текущей проблемой и моим вопросом.** Что я делаю не так и/или чего я не увидел в документации?
**Почему Centrifuge не может подключиться к DonationAlerts** в своём первичном подключении, в котором, судя по документации, ничего лишнего, кроме url подключения, не нужно?

И это при том, что:

```
const socket = new WebSocket(DAws);
socket.addEventListener('message', event => {...});
socket.send(JSON.stringify{...});
```

Работает прекрасно.
Т.е. сейчас я с помощью `new WebSocket()` могу получать все необходимые токены, id-шники и каналы, но не могу подписаться на канал, т.к. 1) судя по документации подписываться надо в том же соединении, что и были получены предыдущие данные 2) `new WebSocket()` разумеется не умеет в subscription.

В тикете в ТП DonationAlerts по данному вопросу я получил ответ-отписку "*Сами не знаем, почему не работает )))*".

Answer (score 0):

Сам столкнулся с этой ошибкой.
Если я правильно понимаю, проблема в протоколе, судя по [этой части документации](https://github.com/centrifugal/centrifugal.dev/blob/c54526ce566e70df6b0ce9d72acc1b612480894e/versioned_docs/version-3/server/codes.md?plain=1#L145).

Но в новой версии такой ошибки вообще нет. Значит скорее всего DonationAlerts использует 3 или даже 2 версию Centrifugo. Попробуйте использовать более старый пакет SDK.

Comment: На версии `^2.8.5`:
`start connecting`
`Status disconnected -> connecting`
`reason is an advice object { reason: 'bad request', reconnect: false }`
`disconnected: bad request false`
`Status connecting -> disconnected`

На 3 и 4 - аналогично 5.

Comment: Я проверял на Go, версии зависимостей SDK: protocol v0.7.3, centrifuge-go v0.8.3; Версии актуальны для centrifugo версии 3. Коннект заработал. Попробуйте посмотреть документацию версии 3, и какая версия ws там используется, и поставьте аналогичную